# Using xpath in Gatling 1.5.6 to extract data from an HTML file containing entities

Tags: html, xpath, sax, saxparser, gatling

I am using Gatling 1.5.6, and part of the load test requires me to extract an ID from some HTML returned from the server. However, the HTML includes `&agrave;`, and Xerces' DOMParser gets tripped up on this with the following error message:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "agrave" was referenced, but not declared.
```

According to the documentation for Gatling 2, the option `expandEntityReferences` can be set to `false` to avoid this but the option doesn't seem to work in Gatling 1.5.6.

What are my options? Is there a system property at the SAX/Xerces level that could be used to disable the expansion of entity references?

I can't change the HTML returned by the site I am testing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use XPath with an HTML document, which is not well formed XML. Use something suited to HTML, such as [CSS selectors](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.3/http/http_check.html?highlight=css%20selectors#http-response-body).

Note that Gatling 1.5 is no longer maintained and that you should migrate to Gatling 2.